# how can I use gem from vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I packed gem into my Vendor folder (Vendor/Cache/youtube-g5.0.1.gem) but I'm not sure how to use it in environment.rb
config.gem "youtube-g" doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

I'm using Rails 2.3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it needs to be unpacked and not in the .gem file. Also try this one: http://gemsonrails.rubyforge.org/